# Need to fetch Application Data from app.config in windows 8.1 app same as appsetting in web.config

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing `windows 8.1` application, I want to fetch application data in my code behind using c#, Application data must be store in a file like `app.config`.

Is there any way to fetch data same as what we can do in `web.config` using `appSetting`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you need an alternative then you can set/get values from `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/dn263230.aspx)

Comment: no i need a physical file to save data, app.config would be good

Comment: Ok. There is no `app.config` file by default in windows 8.1 apps. You can create a xml/json properties file and the parse it in your code. It will be similar to `app.config` file.